# Sans serif glyphs in Noto Sans Math

Tags: unicode-math, math-fonts, opentype, noto

Related: https://github.com/notofonts/math/issues/14#issuecomment-1469979121

How can use actual sans letters from the Noto Sans Math font for typesetting mathematics?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
\setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular.otf}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum
    \[\int\sum\oint ABCabc[]()123 \Gamma\Delta\alpha \beta \symsfit{\alpha\beta}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: noto sans math]

Latin and Greek letters are serif, except for uppercase Greek (I don't know why uppercase Greek is sans). How do I change them to be sans? `\symsfit` gives serif letters as well instead of sans.

---

Noto Sans Math GitHub link: https://github.com/notofonts/math

Answer (score 4):

As I commented on that (closed) github issue this seems to be a lost opportunity to have a sans serif math font.

For latin letters you can use `\symsfit` but the Unicode sans math alphabets don't have Greek, so you rely on the font designer...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
\setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular.otf}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum
    \[\int\sum\oint \symsfit{ABCabc}[]()123 \Gamma\Delta\alpha \beta \symsfit{\alpha\beta}\]
\end{document}
```

The Greek is "almost sans"  an alternative would be to take Greek from the text font

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
\setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular.otf}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum
    \[\int\sum\oint \symsfit{ABCabc}[]()123 \textit{ΓΔαβ} \textit{αβ}\]
\end{document}
```

The vertical aligment is off in the version I have, but that's a different issue.

Comment: One can also use the upright greek sans, [that is available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pem8z.png).

Comment: " ...this seems to be a lost opportunity to have a sans serif math font." Does this mean that the font is "wrong", i.e. is this supposed to a bug (although Simon does not say it is)? What should the glyphs be according to the unicode standards? As you pointed out, Fira (and Lato) both have sans serif glyphs. In the MathML screenshot the Fred posted, the integral, summation symbols, brackets, etc. are sans and the letters serif. This looks really ugly in my humble, non-expert opinion.

Comment: Also, the upright Greek math is sans;shouldn't it be serif as well?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis it is by design but I think the design is wrong, and the glyphs should not have serifs

Comment: "What should the glyphs be according to the unicode standards?" well that's the thing: Unicode does not specify glyph shapes. If a font designer chooses to call a font `foobar sans` but have it contain glyphs with serifs, it's not wrong, just ... strange @ApoorvPotnis

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer and comments.

Comment: By the way, do you know if Simon Cozens is the designer of the font, or he is just the person who added the math table? I was thinking of requesting the font designer to consider changing the glyphs to sans.

Comment: I think he's done all the math (starting from the existing Noto Sans, of course) but you can check the git log @ApoorvPotnis

Answer (score 2):

You can kitbash the letters from Noto Sans and Noto Sans Mono as the math alphabets.

Here’s a template (not extensively tested) that attempts to work around the deficiencies of Noto Sans Math.  It loads STIX Two (which has an OpenType MATH table and reasonably-similar metrics) as the main math font, then loads all math symbols from Noto Sans Math, then loads the Noto Sans family over all serif fonts in Noto Sans Math.

This still has several problems: the big operators and left/right punctuation do not resize.  You might try taking these from a different math font, such as KpMath-Sans or Fira Math.  There are no superscripts or subscripts.  When Noto Sans becomes a variable font, you might set `script-features=` and `sscript=features=` to widen them.  The sans-serif math alphabets look identical to the regular ones.  I might have missed some glyphs the font has or selected some it does not.  Etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{NotoSansMath-Regular}[ range={"00-"FF, "2100-"214F, "2190-"23FF, "25A0-"25FF,
    "27C0-"27FF, "2900-"295F, "2980-"2BFF,
    cal, bfcal, sfup, bfsfup, sfit, bfsfit, frak, bffrak, bb, bbit}]
\setmathfont{NotoSans-Regular}[range={up,"2000-"206F}]
\setmathfont{NotoSans-Italic}[range=it]
\setmathfont{NotoSans-Bold}[range=bfup]
\setmathfont{NotoSans-BoldItalic}[range=bfit]
\setmathfont{NotoSansMono-Regular}[range=tt]

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum
    \[\int\sum\oint ABCabc[]()123 \Gamma\Delta\alpha \beta \symsfit{\alpha\beta}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Math sample]